# error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'ref' with no type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, vmime

I have got this error.The code is below:
I have integrated vmime libraries in my code.Now i need to implement timeout handler with specific timeout entry 30sec here, as per the requirement so implementing this part of the code.

```
class myTimeoutHandler : public vmime :: net :: timeoutHandler {
    public:
     bool isTimeOut()
    {
        return(getTime()>=m_last + 30);
    }
    void resetTimeOut()
    {
        m_last = getTime();
    }
     bool handleTimeOut()
    {
        logMsg(DEBUG,2,"Connection Timed Out!");
        return true;
    }
private:

 const unsigned int getTime() const

 {
    return vmime::platform::getHandler()->getUnixTime();
 }
unsigned int m_last;
};

class myTimeoutHandlerFactory : public vmime::net::timeoutHandlerFactory
{
    public:
        ref <timeoutHandler> create ()
        {
            return vmime::create <myTimeoutHandler>();
        }
};
```

I tried giving vmime::ref in the place of ref , it gives new error,

```
Svr.h:158: error: 'timeoutHandler' was not declared in this scope
Svr.h:158: error: template argument 1 is invalid
```

Can someone please help.Thanks

EDIT:

Iam calling this part of the code in my.C file like this

```
tr->setTimeoutHandlerFactory(vmime::create <myTimeoutHandlerFactory>());
```

Comment: Should it be `vmime::ref<myTimeoutHandler>`?

Comment: No, look closely. `myTimeoutHandler` vs. `timeoutHandler`.

Comment: oh ya thank you so much sftrabbit.So dumb of me.

Comment: Okay, it was just a guess, but I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't have a type called `timeoutHandler` but you do have one called `myTimeoutHandler`. Perhaps you meant:

```
vmime::ref<myTimeoutHandler>
```

Or maybe you want the `timeoutHandler` defined in the `vmime::net` namespace:

```
vmime::ref<vmime::net::timeoutHandler>
```

Comment: one small doubt, cant we use the parent class ref in there as iam inheriting from it.
    class myTimeoutHandler : public vmime :: net :: timeoutHandler

Comment: @user862833 You could do `vmime::ref<vmime::net::timeoutHandler>` but then I'm not sure the conversion from the result of `vmime::create<myTimeoutHandler>()` will work as you expect.

Comment: I get this error when i call with timeoutHandler.

Svr.h:158: error: invalid covariant return type for 'virtual vmime::utility::ref<myTimeoutHandler> myTimeoutHandlerFactory::create()'

Comment: It compiled with vmime::ref<vmime::net::timeoutHandler>. Thanks a ton!

Comment: can u make this as the ans.